# Sending page no in URL request issue. Getting success but empty result

Tags: ios, swift, request, alamofire

My Api is having Constants.getliked = "get-liked-story?page=1" at it's tail. I am requesting via alamofire but not getting the response. How can I send page number which includes ? and = sign.

```
let url : String = Constants.wevlrBaseUrl + Constants.privateLink + Constants.getliked

       //let sv = UIViewController.displaySpinner(onView: view)
        let userToken = UserDefaultValues.authToken
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer " + userToken!]
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "page": "1" ]
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters,headers:headers).responseJSON { response in

            print("request-",response.request!)
            print("response-",response.response!)
            print("data-",response.data!)
            print("result-",response.result)

            debugPrint(response)

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("json: \(JSON)")
            }
        }
```

output:

[Request]: GET http://169.65.125.111/abcd/public/api/v1/get-liked-story?page=1

[Response]:  { URL: http://169.65.125.111/abcd/public/api/v1/get-liked-story?page=1 } 
{ 
Status Code: 200, Headers 
{
    "Cache-Control" =     (
        "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "Keep-Alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        2
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Mon, 07 Oct 2019 11:37:43 GMT"
    );
    Expires =     (
        "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
    );
    "Keep-Alive" =     (
        "timeout=5, max=99"
    );
    Pragma =     (
        "no-cache"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)"
    );
} }

[Data]: 2 bytes

[Result]: SUCCESS: (
)

[Timeline]: Timeline: { "Request Start Time": 592141063.093, "Initial Response Time": 592141063.178, "Request Completed Time": 592141063.178, "Serialization Completed Time": 592141063.178, "Latency": 0.086 secs, "Request Duration": 0.086 secs, "Serialization Duration": 0.000 secs, "Total Duration": 0.086 secs }

json: (
)

Comment: Pass `nil` for `params` as `Alamofire.request(url, parameters: nil,  headers:headers)`. Print your final `url` and see if it is the same url needed by the backend.

Comment: Postman is showing the result, But my response is empty even after getting success and also getting element count as 2. :/

Comment: element count is no. of item in array. I have edited the output.

Comment: Actually this means, everything on client side is fine. It's your backend that has problem. It is sending an empty array. If there was anything wrong with your request, it should throw a proper error instead of `success` response and an empty list.

Comment: ok thank you I will check it once again.

Comment: It was a backend issue. :p

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this value for the variables in Constants

```
let wevlrBaseUrl =  "https://stackoverflow.com"
let privateLink =  "/questions"
let getliked =  "/get-liked-story?page=1"
```

then use Alamofire request method with url and headers parameters only

Comment: not working, actually i am not getting the data value. I am getting the likedDataList as empty array :(